# Hangman Game not Printing Out Correct Letters Guessed

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, valueerror

New programmer here making their first game- hangman!
Basically, I have a global list of random words (I'll add more later), a global call that prints out a random word (for testing), a method where the user guesses a letter at a time. In the user input method, the word is also printed out with asterisks in place of the letters that are incorrect.

I am currently in the part where a user enters a letter and it is being checked if it is in the computer's word. I get this error that reads:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Here is my main code- it's a little messy but please give me any pointers!

```
import random
'''
hangman components:

-dictionary of words
-computer chooses a word from the wordlist
-the word has to be converted into an array or looped through or checking index
-does the user want to guess a letter?
    if the letter is in the word, show it/print it out
    

'''
#simple hangman game with a preloaded list of words!

class hangmanGame():
    
    global wordList 
    wordList = ['cat','dog','apple','pineapple']
    global computer_choice
    computer_choice = random.choice(wordList)
    
    def computer(self):
        #getter method which returns what choice the computer made for the word
        print("The word is %s" % computer_choice)
    
    def user_input(self):
        #method where the user enters a letter, and it is checked whether it is in the word or not. if it is- remove the * and keep going
        #you get 10 turns!
        
        for letter in computer_choice:
            x = print("*")
        
        turns = 0
        letter_choice = input("enter in a letter to check if it is in the word:").lower( )
        turns = turns+1
        #check if the chosen letter is in the computer's word
        # if it is, then print out asterisks except for the correct letter
        for (i,letters) in computer_choice:
            if letter_choice == computer_choice(i):
                print(letters)
            else:
                print("*")
```

I have been running it in Jupyter notebook, here is the second cell with the calls I have been using:

```
hmg =  hangmanGame()
print(hmg.computer())
print(hmg.user_input())
```

Currently, it prints out:

```
The word is dog #randomly generated
None
*
*
*
enter in a letter to check if it is in the word:d
```

I am not too sure why the "None" appears- if you do please let me know! the rest of the error says this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-f471a116dcad> in <module>
      1 hmg =  hangmanGame()
      2 print(hmg.computer())
----> 3 print(hmg.user_input())

<ipython-input-1-6ce94e2f00a5> in user_input(self)
     36         #check if the chosen letter is in the computer's word
     37         # if it is, then print out asterisks except for the correct letter
---> 38         for (i,letters) in computer_choice:
     39             if letter_choice == computer_choice(i):
     40                 print(letters)

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1):

the problem is you are giving two indexes to the list `computer_choice` in the for loop on line 38. What did you want to call by adding the `i` value in there? I'm assuming you are trying to check if the input letter, `letter_choice` matches any letter in the randomly chosen word, for that you won't need two variables anyway, just try

```
for letters in computer_choice:
            if letter_choice == computer_choice(letters):
                print(letters)
```

which should print the right guessed letter!

Comment: Also, you would use two indexes that way if your list was two dimensional, in which case you would make a call as say, `your_list[i, j]` which would call the item from the column with index i, and the row with index j.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just focus on your question about why the word `None` appears.

TLDR; just replace `print` with `return` in your `computer()` method. Explanation below

You have created a method within your class called computer.
You have defined it with:

```
def computer(self):
        #getter method which returns what choice the computer made for the word
        print("The word is %s" % computer_choice)
```

The issue is that there is no return statement. Since you are using Jupyter Notebooks, the notebook cell will return the value of a function that has been run. You function (or in this case class method), has no return value.

Try changing the print() statement to a return statement. i.e.

```
def computer(self):
        #getter method which returns what choice the computer made for the word
        return "The word is %s" % computer_choice
```

Comment: I should add, if you were just running your original code as a python file, that 'None' wouldn't show up. It's just because you are using a notebook